# Magento2 price per store view

Tags: magento2, price, multistore

In a project im working on it is crucial to be able to set a price per specific store view. I have already tried BSS Commerce extension. but it is not working that well and is badly supported.

In magento1 i just set the attribute in the database to storeview and worked fine. But in Magento2 it does not work that way. 
Does anyone have any experience in this?